# Regex to find the word just before and after a keyword?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

What RegEx would match the word (including special characters) right after a keyword?

E.g. In the following text, using the keyword "equals", the RegEx would match "'1'", "Two" and "3"

```
Status equals '1' or Status equals Two or Status equals 3
```

Comment: Is `equals (\S+)` what you are looking for?

Comment: It greatly depends on your regex engine. Please specify the programming language or tool you are using it in.

Comment: @stribizhev It's running on angular thanks

Comment: @m.cekiera, tried that answer but it doesn't match the '1' word, must be the special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind.

```
(?<=\bequals )\S+
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, thanks for the super quick reply! The example above seems to match just the first result (i.e. matches "'1'" only). Is there some regex magic to get it to match "Two" and "3" as well?

Comment: @Lenny. Use `global` flag

Comment: ya, you need to use global flag `g`